# How to classify class, function and function property in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've 3 objects like these:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }
}

let Add = function (a, b) {
    return a + b
};

let Math = {
    multiply: function (x, y) {
        return x * y
    }
};
```

As you can `see`, `Person` is a class, `Add` and `Math.multiply` are functions.

My question: How to classify `class` and `functions` in this case?

My question comes from: `Person` looks like a function, like this:

```
let Person = function (name, age) {
    this._name = name;
    this._age = age;
};
```

Also, there are no problems if I declare an object to get new instance of `Add` function:

```
let result = new Add(2, 3); // this is allowed although it just needn't
```

[new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) says:

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or
>   of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

All of 3 cases, `Person`, `Add` and `Math.multiply` are constructors. So:

```
let person = new Person('Hermione', 18); // allowed
let result = new Add(2, 3); // allowed
result = new Math.multiply(2, 2); // allowed
```

Then, because all of them are constructors, it's so difficult to classify `class` and `function` (for me).

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: sorry, what is your end goal? to "classify class and function" ... in what sense? To what ends do you need this classification? Will a classification change how your code works?

Comment: @JaromandaX In my example. a `class` looks like a `function`, and a `function` looks like a `class`. I want to classify it. `Person` is a class, `Add` and `Math.multiply` are functions.

Comment: there, you've just classified them

Comment: I think the question is HappyCoding is asking is "how can one tell at runtime whether something was declared as a class or as a function?"

Comment: to paraphrase ... `javascript says no`

Comment: In 99.9% of real world every day tasks you never should do that in run time. Just look how it is defined you're done.

Comment: Not exactly related, but `Math` might be a bad variable name ...

Comment: "`Person` is a class, `Add` and `Math.multiply` are functions." --- here you have just classified it yourself.

Comment: @zerkms That's `I/you/we see`. But in javascript I can use `Add` and `Math.multiply` as classes. Is it better if I can use a function like a class? No, it isn't.

Comment: @HappyCoding and? You see with your eyes that something is a class. What else do you need? "Is it better if I can use a function like a class? No, it isn't" --- so, don't.

Comment: @HappyCoding: I've fixed an error in my answer: You *can* tell whether a function was created with `class` or `function`. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think as you've mentioned. It's simply. A `class` requires a `new` operator while a `function` doesn't. And in my example, 3 cases accept `new` operator. Many thanks! Great explaining!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your question stems from quite understandable confusion: Despite the `class` syntax, JavaScript doesn't have classes as distinct from functions like some class-based OOP languages do (Java, C#, C++). `class` syntax creates a *function* and associated properties on the object referenced by that function's `prototype` property. It's not a separate thing. See below the bar for more.

Further, JavaScript didn't originally make any distinction between normal functions and constructor functions; it was purely a matter of how you used used them (e.g., via `new` or calling them directly). As of ES2015 which introduced both `class` syntax and arrow functions, the language is moving toward distinguishing different kinds of functions (the ones created via `class` will throw an error if you call them without `new`; arrow functions will throw an error if you *do* call them via `new`).

If your goal is to look at `Person` in code and know whether it was created with `class` or `function` without calling it, the only way to do that is to convert it to a string and look at the result. The specification [requires](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.tostring) that `Function.prototype.toString` return a string that...

> ...must have the syntax of a *FunctionDeclaration*, *FunctionExpression*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, *GeneratorExpression*, *ClassDeclaration*, *ClassExpression*, *ArrowFunction*, *MethodDefinition*, or *GeneratorMethod* depending upon the actual characteristics of the object.

So for instance, if I've used `class Foo { }`, then `Foo.toString()` has to return a `class` declaration or expression, whereas if I've used `function Foo { }` instead, it must return a `function` declaration or expression. So you could work it out with a regular expression.

In a comment you've asked zerkms

> But in javascript I can use `Add` and `Math.multiply` as classes. Is it better if I can use a function like a class? No, it isn't.

It completely depends on how `Add` and `X.multiply` *(I really wouldn't shadow the built-in `Math` object)* are defined: It may well make sense to call them via `new`. It's not uncommon for an object property to be a reference to a constructor function:

```
let Nifty = {
    Stuff: class {
        constructor(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
};
let x = new Nifty.Stuff("Coolness");
console.log(x.name); // "Coolness"
```

or

```
// Better not to do this, but it's allowed
let Nifty = {
    Stuff: function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
};
let x = new Nifty.Stuff("Coolness");
console.log(x.name); // "Coolness"
```

---

Re `class` creating functions: That's literally what it does:

```js
class Foo {
}
console.log(typeof Foo); // "function"
```

In fact, this:

```
class Foo {
}
```

roughly translates to

```
let Foo = function() {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo)) { // This check isn't quite right, but it's close
        throw new TypeError("Class constructor Foo cannot be invoked without 'new'");
    }
};
```

and

```
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    sayHello() {
        console.log(`Hi, my name is ${name}!`);
    }
}
```

roughly translates to

```
let Foo = function(name) {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo)) { // This check isn't quite right, but it's close
        throw new TypeError("Class constructor Foo cannot be invoked without 'new'");
    }
    this.name = name;
};

Foo.prototype.sayHello = function sayHello() {
        console.log("Hi, my name is " + name + "!");
    }
};
```

Comment: "JavaScript doesn't have classes as distinct from functions" --- this needs some elaboration.

Comment: @zerkms: I followed it immediately with *"`class` syntax creates a function and associated properties on the object referenced by that function's `prototype` property."* which seems like a fair bit of elaboration to me. I did go back and add examples, though.

Comment: "class syntax creates a function" --- my point was more, is it required to be so by the standard?

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, it is: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation

Comment: yep, I finally bothered enough to check it as well (in the es2015 spec though). Thanks.